# Change privacy settings on Hangouts

Tags: google-hangouts

Hangouts shows a green phone icon when someone is on a voice call.

Is it possible to hide this indicator to other users so nobody knows if I'm on a call?

Comment: Welcome! Good question. Please [edit] your question in order to improve its title so that it forms a complete grammatically correct sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, press the 3 bars on top left, choose **Settings**, under **Account Settings** select your username (*username@gmail.com*), select "**Share your status**" and uncheck **Device**

Keep in mind, this will remove the little mobile icon when you're chatting as well. I have found that some of my friends message me more if they think I'm on my computer.